# JQuery .not() function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So i'm having problems with the jQuery .not() function.

All divs effected collapse as normal with a toggle but the problem lies within the closing every other div class. If you've opened the first div, clicking on any of the other divs closes it but if you click on any of the other divs first then another they don't close.

Here is the code

```
function hideNot(id) {
    $("#teamMemberDescription").not("." + id).hide();
}

$("#teamMember.paulturner").click(function(){
    hideNot("paulturner");
    $("#teamMemberDescription.paulturner").toggle(500);
});

$("#teamMember.paulblake").click(function(){
    hideNot("paulblake");
    $("#teamMemberDescription.paulblake").toggle(500);
});

$("#teamMember.bobhook").click(function(){
    hideNot("bobhook");
    $("#teamMemberDescription.bobhook").toggle(500);
});

$("#teamMember.yvonnemclean").click(function(){
    hideNot("yvonnemclean");
    $("#teamMemberDescription.yvonnemclean").toggle(500);
});
```

Here's the html

```
<div id="standardContainer" class="teamPage">
        <div id="standardContent">

                <h1 class="entry-title"><whiteblocker>MEET THE TEAM</whiteblocker></h1>

                <div id="teamBanner">
                    <img src="<?php the_field('team_group_image');?>" width="100%">
                </div>

                <div id="teamDescription">
                    <h2>PREVENTEC - WHO WE ARE</h2>
                    <?php the_field('team_description');?>
                </div>

                <div id="teamMembers">
                    <?php if(get_field('team_members')): ?>         
                        <?php while(the_repeater_field('team_members')): ?>
                            <?php $memberName = get_sub_field('member_name');?>
                            <?php $memberName = str_replace(" ","", $memberName);?>
                            <?php $memberName = strtolower($memberName);?>

                            <div id="teamMember" class="<?php echo $memberName;?>">
                                <img src="<?php the_sub_field('member_photo');?>">
                                <div class="teamMemberDetails">
                                    <h3><?php the_sub_field('member_name');?></h3>
                                    <h4><?php the_sub_field('member_position');?></h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif;?>  
                </div>  

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="teamDetailsContainer">
        <div id="teamDetailsContent">
            <?php if(get_field('team_members')): ?>         
                <?php while(the_repeater_field('team_members')): ?>
                    <?php $memberName = get_sub_field('member_name');?>
                    <?php $memberName = str_replace(" ","", $memberName);?>
                    <?php $memberName = strtolower($memberName);?>

                    <div id="teamMemberDescription" class="<?php echo $memberName;?>">
                        <h1><?php the_sub_field('member_name');?></h1>
                        <?php the_sub_field('member_description');?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: You have a problem selecting elements but don't even show the document structure? You have a UI behavior problem but don't even include a functional demo?

Comment: you have multiple divs with the same id?!

Comment: Element `id`s must be unique. It looks like you have several elements with the ids `teamMember` and `teamMemberDescription`. Start by changing those to classes.

Comment: This is wrong if you're trying to select something by its ID. `.not("." + id)` It should then be: `.not("#" + id)`. Also, IDs should be unique.

Comment: He seems to use then as classes, but, calls then id. `$("#teamMemberDescription").not("." + id).hide();` is for classes like `paulturner` -> `$("#teamMemberDescription.paulturner").toggle(500);`

Comment: I noticed that probably you're referring to the element class as id. Name your variables properly to make things easier to understand.

Comment: Please post the document the **browser sees**, not your PHP code.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: @klauskpm I just noticed that. Thanks!

Comment: @MelanciaUK I believe `id` is used to pass a class name, not actually the element id

Comment: can you post your HTML and not the PHP?

Answer (score -1):

just guessing: your strcture should be

```
// HTML
<div id="description">
    <div id="paul">...</div>
    <div id="...">...</div>
</div>

// JQUERY
function hideNot(name) {
    $("#description > div").not("#" + name).hide();
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with the answer? it just works and totally matches to original question before all updates! its really fun to help people not asking proper questions!